# What part of Spark SQL parse SQL statements and create execution plan?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Assuming the following query:

```
select * from my_table
```

what part of Spark parses the sql and create the execution plan?

Does Spark SQL execution engine have its own sql parser that translates it to his own execution model? how it works?

I got exception for some functions that spark does not support them yet, does it means spark parse the sql query ? does each other execution engine does it too?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

In Spark SQL it's [AstBuilder](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/catalyst/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/parser/AstBuilder.scala#L45-L46) that builds a abstract syntax tree of logical operators and expressions.

> The AstBuilder converts an ANTLR4 ParseTree into a catalyst `Expression`, `LogicalPlan` or `TableIdentifier`.

`AstBuilder` is a ANTLR-based SQL parser that uses the SQL grammar described in [SqlBase.g4](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/catalyst/src/main/antlr4/org/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/parser/SqlBase.g4) (that was incidentally borrowed from Facebook's Presto with additional support for Hive and PostgreSQL statements).

You can play with supported queries using [SparkSession.sql](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession@sql(sqlText:String):org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame):

> **sql(sqlText: String): DataFrame** Executes a SQL query using Spark, returning the result as a DataFrame. The dialect that is used for SQL parsing can be configured with 'spark.sql.dialect'.

You could go low-level and use the parser directly:

```
import spark.sessionState.sqlParser
scala> :type sqlParser
org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.ParserInterface
```

Use `parsePlan` method (among the other parsing methods) that accepts a SQL text.

```
scala> sqlParser.parsePlan("select * from myTable")
res1: org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan =
'Project [*]
+- 'UnresolvedRelation `myTable`
```

With a logical plan (for SQL) Spark SQL uses something I call a **structured query execution pipeline** (aka [QueryExecution](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/execution/QueryExecution.scala#L36-L40)):

> **QueryExecution** The primary workflow for executing relational queries using Spark. Designed to allow easy access to the intermediate phases of query execution for developers.

Every `Dataset` has its own `QueryExecution` that you can access using `queryExecution` property:

```
val q = spark.range(5)
val qe = q.queryExecution
```

You can access the phases of a query execution using `analyzed`, `withCachedData`, `optimizedPlan`, `sparkPlan`, `executedPlan`, `toRdd` lazy values that are all together displayed using `explain` operator.

```
scala> q.explain(extended = true)
== Parsed Logical Plan ==
Range (0, 5, step=1, splits=Some(8))

== Analyzed Logical Plan ==
id: bigint
Range (0, 5, step=1, splits=Some(8))

== Optimized Logical Plan ==
Range (0, 5, step=1, splits=Some(8))

== Physical Plan ==
*Range (0, 5, step=1, splits=8)
```

Comment: OMG, The writer of Mastering spark answered to me...
do you know how it works on other execution engines, does impala/ tez has their own parser?

Comment: Know nothing about Impala and Tez. Sorry. I don't spend my precious time on obsolete things ;-)

Comment: @JacekLaskowski does the sql gets converted to RDD behind the scenes or scala code and gets executed as Java byte code ?

Comment: @sriharikalicharanTummala Yes. Structured queries (in any language like SQL, Scala, Java or others) are converted to Java byte code whenever possible (to avoid interpreted execution and use code-gen instead).

Comment: @JacekLaskowski thank you , so ANTLR converts SQL grammer to Java Byte code and executes on Hadoop ?

Comment: Please ask a separate question to let others learn from our conversation. OK?