# Scala code to split a select sql query when i have comma inside anothe column

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have select query as below:

```sql
select id, name as emp_name, case when coalesce(sal,0)=0 then 0 else 1 end as emp_sal from employee;
```

I want yo write scala code in which the query is broken down into list of columns .  If i do splitting based on "," then the case condition "," is breaking down the column into two

What am getting when it gets into a for loop:

```
"id"
"name as emp_name"
"case when coalesce(sal"
"0)=0 then 0 else 1 end as emp_sal"
```

My expected result when it gets into a for loop:

```
"id"
"name as emp_name"
"case when coalesce(sal,0)=0 then 0 else 1 end as emp_sal"
```

Here is my code snippet
// Your SQL query

val sqlQuery = "select id, name as emp_name, case when coalesce(sal,0)=0 then 0 else 1 end as emp_sal from employee"

// Extract the part between "select" and "from"

val selectPart = sqlQuery.split("(?i)select ")(1).split("(?i) from")(0).trim

// Split the select part into individual columns while preserving complex expressions

val columns = selectPart.split(",").map(_.trim)

// Iterate over the columns and print them

for (column <- columns) {
println(s""""$column"""")
}

But as said this is still splitting my columns based on (",") even inside the case condition which isn't my ideal case expecting

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: What would be the rules to split? Sounds like you need a parser, a simple regex won't be enough. If this is Spark, there might be utilities that can parse the query for you.

Comment: This may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44242068/what-part-of-spark-sql-parse-sql-statements-and-create-execution-plan

Comment: I have edited my question, adding my code snippet which i have tried, kindly help to look into it , Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Per [Gaël J](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5389127/ga%c3%abl-j), you should use a proper parser with an SQL grammer or, if you are ok with using internals, use the Spark parser directly and interrogate the resulting trees/plans.

In Spark terms it's a projection you are looking for, to ease things you could wrap the first query in a "select * from ()" to ensure you get a simpler parse.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkSqlParser
/* parsers can only be constructed in a valid session */
val parser = SparkSession.getActiveSession.map(_.sessionState.sqlParser).getOrElse {
      new SparkSqlParser()
    }
/* an issue when parsing is thrown rather than Either/Try etc. */
    val plan =
      try {
        parser.parsePlan(theSqlString)
...
```

The plan trees can be difficult to browse at first but it's an almost complete grammar and if it's target usage is Spark anyway it's ideal for that use case.

Be aware until the plan is analysed etc. you will have everything as "Undefined" and "unresolved" but it's enough to read functions, attribute names etc.

What it will not do for you is handle automatic projection name creation if there is a function call without a user defined name with it.  It will similarly not verify if the SQL is actually usable (e.g. a field used is actually present in a datasource or the SQL will even run at all), it only verifies that the sql has a chance of running.

[sample usage for handling correlated subqueries](https://github.com/sparkutils/quality/blob/aa01449ab1a0019b7b8a79db1784dd7fb30cebab/src/main/scala/com/sparkutils/quality/impl/RuleImpl.scala#L59)